# Can't make inheritance work

Tags: java, inheritance, super

Have these two classes.

```
public class TVChannel
{
    /**
    * Fields
    */
    private String name;
    private int length;
    private int day;
    private String start;
    private int year;
    private String comment;

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public TVChannel (String name, int length, int day, String start, int year)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.length=length;
        this.day=day;
        this.start=start;
        this.year=year;
        comment=" ";
    }

    public void changeDay(int newday){day=newday;}
    public void changeStart(String start){this.start=start;}
    public String giveName(){return name;}
    public int giveLength(){return length;}
    public int dajDay(){return day;}

    public String toString (){return name + " " + length + ":" + start + ":" + year;}
}
```

And another one is:

```
public class Quiz extends TVChannel
{
    private String author;
    private String host;
    public String giveHost(){return host;}
}
```

So I'm trying to make TVChannel a superclass here. But when I compile Quiz, error message appears.

> Constructor TVCHannel in class TVChannel cannot be applied to given
>   types.
>   required:java.lang.String,int,int,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String.
>   found:no arguments actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Never had this problem in class before.

I tried solving it like this:

```
public Quiz(String name, int length, int day, String start, int year) 
{
    super(name, length, day, start, year);
}
```

But then I get this:

> error: invalid method declaration; return type required?

with Public Quiz.

Why is Java mistaking a constructor for a method?

Comment: Can not reproduce this (http://ideone.com/EI7tcK). Please provide an [mcve] (Your approach to add the constructor is correct - constructors are not inherited, and the super class only has the constructor with those five parameters, hence the sub class **must** call this constructor through `super(...)`).

Comment: can you provide your main() method?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Check for typos and clean and rebuild. Also check parantheses. Where did you declare the CTOR? In your snippet above it seems to reside outside of the class scope.

Comment: please provide the whole class file.

Comment: you may add constructor without params in parent class:  public TVChannel() { }. In that case you dont need to have constructor with params in Quiz.

Comment: As I read your error, I think you made a typo with the letter `H` see the part "Constructor TVC**H**annel in class TVC**h**annel".

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor from "TVCHannel" to "TVChannel".  You may also want to use line code identifier to help you track down the typo.